# Correr script em maquinas XP

Tags: script, powershell

Tenho um *script* a correr correctamente em maquinas 7, mas em XP não corre.
Se correr localmente, faz o que se pretende, mas via GPO não.
O *script* verifica a OU do computador, verifica um ficheiro `.csv` e coloca *icons* respectivos no *desktop* do utilizador.
Com `gpresult`, diz que corre.
Na consola das políticas dá um erro:

> An unknown error occurred while data was gathered for this extension.
>   Details: Not found

*Script*:

```
$links = Import-Csv -Path \\Share$\links.csv

function GetPCOU{
   $SysInfo = New-Object -ComObject "ADSystemInfo"
   $Computer = [ADSI]("LDAP://{0}" -f $SysInfo.GetType().InvokeMember("ComputerName", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::GetProperty, $null, $SysInfo, $null))
   return ([ADSI]$Computer.Parent).OU
} 

for($i=0; $i-le $links.length-1; $i++){

    if ($links[$i].ou -eq (GetPCOU)) {
        $shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
        $desktop = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')

        $shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut("$desktop\app1.url")
        $shortcut.TargetPath = $links[$i].xx
        $shortcut.Save()

        $shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut("$desktop\app2.url")
        $shortcut.TargetPath = $links[$i].xy
        $shortcut.Save()
    }
}
```

Links file:

```
Ou, app1, app2, appz
OU1, http://xpto.com, http://xxx.xx, http://hhhh.dd
OU2, xxxx, yyyy, zzzz,
```

[Pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28878114/running-powershell-logon-script-on-xp)

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Sei que vc já tem o script pronto.
Mas, já pensou em utilizar as Group Policy Preferences.
vc consegue fazer tudo isso por lá.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731892(v=ws.10).aspx
http://blogs.technet.com/b/grouppolicy/archive/2008/03/04/gp-policy-vs-preference-vs-gp-preferences.aspx

Adriano.